# How to correct syntax highlighting for setting Rails link or form field "class" in Sublime/Textmate 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textmate, sublimetext2, sublimetext

**BACKGROUND:** In Sublime Text and Textmate, the word "class" is incorrectly highlighted when using the new ruby hash format in a Rails link_to or form field:

[image]

**OBJECTIVE:** Is there any way to correctly highlight the "class" keyword as it does when using the old format:

[image]

Comment: Same in RubyMine, if anyone has a solution...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's to do with the precedence in terms of syntax highlighting. Because the keywords for ruby matches "class" it is trying to highlight it as though you had `class MyClass`. Whereas the old format of hashes had the preceding `:` to stop it from being picked up as a keyword.

**Disclaimer**: I'm no expert on this stuff was just tinkering and the following worked for me.

If you edit your Ruby.tmLanguage file (in Packages/Ruby) you can move the section that defines keywords below the section that defines the new ruby 1.9 hash syntax. That way it should prioritize the new hash syntax.

Look for a `<dict>` entry that contains:

```
<dict>
  ....
  <key>name</key>
  <string>keyword.control.ruby</string>
</dict>
```

and put it below the entry like:

```
<dict>
  ....
  <key>name</key>
  <string>constant.other.symbol.ruby.19syntax</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: awesome! for those that need help finding it, moving lines 201-208 and inserting them at line 1570 worked for me.

Comment: I submitted this as a Sublime issue: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/147262-/

Comment: On Mac OS X with Sublime Text 2, the full path for the file is: "/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Ruby/Ruby.tmLanguage"

Comment: Unfortunately the situation is a bit trickier on Sublime Text 3 (beta) for Mac OS X. You have to copy the Ruby language definition file from inside the Sublime Text 3 application here: "/Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages/Ruby.sublime-package". The .sublime-package extension is actually a zip file which you'll need to extract, then open the folder, change the Ruby.tmLanguage file as described above, then rezip the file and then install it by adding it to the "~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages" folder.

Comment: @neon it helped but it was 1568 in my case ;-)